# Laravel Carbon error data missing with casting

Tags: laravel-6

I have a date property, and I try to cast it to the DateTime format during saving.

```php
protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:m',
];
```

In my controller, I have the following method.

```php
public function change(int $gameSerieId, Request $request)
{
    try {
        $gameSerie = GameSerie::findOrFail($gameSerieId);
        $gameSerie->update($request->all());

        return response()->json('ok');
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        throw new GameApiException('Something went wrong!');
    }
}
```

However, I get an error "Data Missing" because my date input format looks like a string: `2019-11-17 21:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the ability of use mutators for set attributes

```
public function setDateAttribute($date)
{
    $this->attributes['date'] = Carbon::make($date);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator